# Jquery autocomplete with AngularJS filter

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I can't get AngularJS filters to work correctly with Jquery autocomplete. Filter works fine when you are typing but if you select item from the autocomplete list result isn't updated until another key press.

Jquery autocomplete:

```
$( "#searchTeam" ).autocomplete({
            source: teamList,
            change: function(event,ui)
            {
                if (ui.item==null)
                {
                    $("#createPeopleForm_team").val('');
                    $("#createPeopleForm_team").focus();
                    angular.element($(this)).triggerHandler('input')
                }
            },
            minLength: 0
        }).focus(function(){
            //Use the below line instead of triggering keydown
            $(this).autocomplete("search");
        });
    });
```

and the input of the filter looks like this:

```
<input id="searchTeam" ng-model="query.team"><br/>
```

Comment: yes,I am using autocomplete with AngularJS and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#searchTeam" ).autocomplete({
            source: teamList,
            change: function(event,ui)
            {
                if (ui.item==null)
                {
                    $("#createPeopleForm_team").val('');
                    $("#createPeopleForm_team").focus();
                    angular.element($(this)).triggerHandler('input')
                }
            },
            minLength: 0
        }).focus(function(){
            //Use the below line instead of triggering keydown
            $(this).autocomplete("search");
$scope.$apply();//might be you missing this
        });
    });
```

might be you need to update bindings manually using $scope.$apply. Try it

Comment: as I mentioned I'm using Jquery autocomplete and code part I provided is Jquery so I $scope is undefined there

Comment: Ok In that case, try to put $scope.$apply just after call to autocomplete occurs...and get back to me, with whatever happens

Comment: `$scope.apply` doesn't work wherever I put it because it's undefined there. I believe I should use `angular.element($(this)).scope().$apply();` but with this even though I don't get any error it doesn't work either.